# .htaccess Redirect all subpages except one

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I redirected Joomla frontpage to different domain using .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule !^(media|administrator) http://newdomain.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works.

I need one URL to exclude from the redirection, in order to gather stats from newsletter component.
So I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php?option=com_mycomponent&ctrl=stats
RewriteRule !^(media|administrator) http://newdomain.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work, although I clear browser cache many times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `THE_RQUEST` srever-varibale not `REQUEST_URI` if you want to match all part of request so change this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php?option=com_mycomponent&ctrl=stats
```

With this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !index\.php\?option=com_mycomponent&ctrl=stats
```

Comment: There is no need to escape `=` , `_` and `&` as these are not regex special characters.